# How to control execution flow in Powershell based on StartWith() result?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, wmi, startswith

Trying get this simple statement working, and I cant understand why it won't output the correct result.

```
$asset = "get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem | select Name"
if ($asset.StartsWith("ME")) {
echo "Asset tag is ok" }
Else 
{ echo "Asset tag needs updating" }
```

For some reason, despite the result from the WMI query being "ME12345" for example, the code outputs "Asset tag needs updating".

Do I need to use an `/F` or something to make the `IF` statement work with the result from the WMI statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is wrapped in double-quotes, so you are passing a string of the command, rather than the actual returned value.

When you change it to a command and the value is returned, it is an object with the property `Name`, and it does not contain a method "StartsWith", instead you can use a comparison operator, and below I've gone with regex that matches lines starting with "ME".

You probably want to use `CIMInstance`, as it is the new version of `WMIObject`.

```
$asset = Get-CimInstance -Class win32_computersystem | Select Name
    if ($asset.Name -match "^ME") {
        Write-Output "Asset tag is ok" 
    }
    Else {
        Write-Output "Asset tag needs updating" 
    }
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that, thankyou- this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$asset = iex 'get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem | select -expand Name'
        if ($asset.tostring().StartsWith("ME")) {
        echo "Asset tag is ok" }
        Else 
        { echo "Asset tag needs updating" }
```

In `$asset` you are not actually executing the string, it is remaining a string, you need to use `iex` or `Invoke-Expression` to invoke the expression, then use expand the property value and execute `StartsWith` on a String variable.